# Folio or booklet, or a better word?

Tags: synonyms

Large hardbound books are printed on little 'booklets', all of the same page count, and then bound together to form one book onto which the hard cover is then attached. Is it wrong to call these separate 'booklets' by the name of 'folios', which I thought was only used to describe the single pages? If not is there a better word than 'booklets'?

A recent discussion with a well known printing company introduced me to this particular usage of the word 'folio' by them...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the word you're looking for is "**signature**", which Merriam-Webster defines as "one unit of a book comprising a group of printed sheets that are folded and stitched together".

Comment: Further research indicates that originally, the word "signature" was used to refer to the _mark_ on each folded sheet that was used to put it in the correct order and orientation in the collected book block.  (I have actually seen these marks on some books, which for example might have "A" in the corner of one page, followed by "B" sixteen pages later.)  From this, the terminology evolved to use "signature" to refer to the entire folded sheet.

Comment: Also, traditionally the words "folio", "quarto", "octavo", etc. refer to the number of times the original printed sheet is folded, and therefore how many pages are in each signature. For a standardized sheet size, this also determines the length and width of the resulting book.

Answer (score 1):

I think these booklets are called "gatherings", each made of multiple folios, where a folio (according to one definition) is a folded sheet on which is printed 4 pages. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Folio

Answer (score 1):

***[Folio](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/folio)*** may refer both to each  printed page folded to form a book, and to a book made up of a number folios;  if you are referring to each singular folded unit, folio is the correct term:

> - A large sheet of paper folded once in the middle, making two leaves or four pages of a book or manuscript.
> - A book or manuscript of the largest common size, usually about 38 centimeters (15 inches) in height, consisting of such folded sheets.

(AHD)